# aws api gateway method with conditional resource id

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a new `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` but the `ResourceId` property depends on a condition.

```
Parameters:
  RestApiId:
    Type: String
  ParentId:
    Type: String
  PathPart:
    Type: String
Conditions:
  WithPathPart:
    Fn::Not:
      - Fn::Equals:
          - Ref: PathPart
          - ""
Resources:
  UriPathPartResource:
    Condition: WithPathPart
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      PathPart:
        Ref: PathPart
      ParentId:
        Ref: ParentId
      RestApiId:
        Ref: RestApiId
  UriResourceMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: RestApiId
      ResourceId:
        Fn::If:
          - WithPathPart
          - UriPathPartResource
          - ParentId
      OperationName:
        Ref: OperationName
```

If `PathPart` is passed as a string, I want to be able to use the `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource` that is created with it, otherwise just use the `ParentId`.
This seemed simple in theory but it's not working for some reason.

Any idea why?

Comment: Does it say something when it's "not working"?